# Very slow https upload to the VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We have:

Last version of x64 VisualSVN Server (3.3.2) on Windows Server 2012 (no antivirus software; default windows firewall is on)

TortoiseSVN client last version (1.9) on Windows 7 (no antivirus software too)

FSFS repository (fresh and almost empty)

We get **~163 kBytes** per second of uploading speed on commit!
What is the root of the problem and how to fix it?

Additional info:

The link between same client\server systems was tested via some custom TCP software and this shows far beyond 10mbps. So this is not network problem (or at least not an obvious one).

Moreover, if we switch server and client sides using the same machines **speed becomes good: 1.5MBps download, 5MBps upload**

This issue exists for at least several previous versions of VSS \ Tortoise.

Tested from several other client machines - same problem.

Tested commit from SmartSVN client - same problem.

Comment: This is impossible to tell without a detailed knowledge of your network / hardware. You should contact the makers of VisualSVN for support.

Comment: @xxbbcc Why do you think that this is a network or even hardware (!) problem? And what knowledge do you mean? Mailed to support, no answer at the moment.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without those details and is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it has nothing to do with programming (SVN usage could be but network speed issues with SVN are definitely out). If it's a software issue with VisualSVN, the support team is the best qualified to answer.

Comment: @xxbbcc You're just writing useless abstract sentences, nothing more.

Comment: Have you taken the time to read the help center? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to an antivirus or firewall installed on the server machine.  *Remove* the antivirus completely, restart the machine and see whether it helps. This seems to be a pretty common issue caused by a faulty antivirus.

Comment: @bahrep There is a default Windows Server 2012 setup, no additional antivirus or firewall software installed.

Comment: MBps is mega*bit* per second, i.e. 1 MBps is approximately equal to 100 kbyte/second. 1.5 MBps and 163 kbyte/second is the same speed.

Comment: @IvanZhakov Go to Wiki and learn the difference between MBs and Mbs.

Comment: @Eug Wikipedia [Data rate units article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Megabyte_per_second) only mentions "Mbps" as alias  for MBit/s, but it doesn't mention "MBps" as alias MB/s. Anyway you should not use such confusing conventions for Stackoverflow questions if you want to get useful answers.